# Change the size of the loss plot of the trained neural network

Tags: neural-networks

I am training with the simple a example of the documentation neural network ([Link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetTrain.html)). I train the net, but and I don´t know how to change the size of the graphics of the loss plot. And when I try to see the Head of the expression a get `GeneralUtilities'TightLabeled`

Here is the code of the example

```
    In[1]:= trained = NetTrain[LinearLayer[],{1->1.9,2->4.1,3->6.0,4->8.1},All];
    In[2]:= trained["LossPlot"]//Head
Out[2]= GeneralUtilities`TightLabeled
```

Even do I try to get the graphic with `"FinalPlots"` but still, returns as a  `GeneralUtilities'TightLabeled` object.

```
In[4]:= Normal[Values[trained["FinalPlots"]]][[1]]//Head
Out[4]= GeneralUtilities`TightLabeled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `GeneralUtilities'TightLabeled` is a special version of labeling function that is similar to `Labeled`.

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True];
GeneralUtilities`TightLabeled[p, {None, "sin(x)", "x"}]
```

[image]

The graph itself can be extracted as the first part, and can be adjusted as usual using `Show`

```
plot = trained["LossPlot"];
Show[plot[[1]], ImageSize -> Medium, FrameLabel -> {"rounds", "loss"},
  ImagePadding -> Automatic, FrameStyle -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]